# EF Core failed to save entity with IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a model class `Category` that has a nullable `ParentId` as a reference to its parent category. I decided to use EF Core 7 and its FluentApi to map this model to the database, but I don't want to use EF Core migrations but rather manually created scripts.

```
CREATE TABLE [Categories] 
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,       
    [Created] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,  
    [ParentId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,        

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)        
)   

ALTER TABLE [Categories] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Cat_Cat] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Categories] ([Id])
```

Model class

```
public class Category
{    
    public long Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public Category? Parent { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Category>? Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();            
}
```

EF Core 7 mapper

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
    {
            builder.ToTable("Categories");
            builder.HasKey(it => it.Id);
            builder.Property(it => it.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            builder.Property(it => it.Created).IsRequired();            
            builder.Property(it => it.Name).IsRequired();   
            builder.HasOne(it => it.Parent)
                .WithMany(c => c.Categories)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId)
                .IsRequired(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the application code.

```
var parentId = 1;  // id of the previously saved category in the DB
Category? parent = await _repository.GetById(parentId, cancellationToken);
var category = new Category 
{
    Name = "test",
    Parent = parent  //if I leave this line out the save will be successfully created              
};

await _repository.Insert(category);

try
{
    await _repository.SaveAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    // Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
}
```

You'll notice that set `ValueGeneratedNever()` on the `Id` property in the mapper and this will be a database responsibility.

I tried to set identity on explicitly in the database:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Categories] ON
```

But I still get

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Update:
On the mapping class I tried each of the following

```
-  builder.Property(it => it.Id).UseIdentityColumn(1,1);
-  builder.Property(it => it.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
-  builder.Property(it => it.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
-  builder.Property(it => it.Id).ValueGeneratedAdd();
```

but I'm still having the same error.

The repository Insert is just an abstraction over db context add

```
public async Task Insert(T entity)
        {
            await _dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please let us know currently database automatically assigning the identity value for `Categories`? And you would like to stop it , I am I right? I think, this `builder.Property(it => it.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();` causing the issue.

Comment: Just remove this line ` builder.Property(it => it.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();`

Comment: @MDFaridUddinKiron actually I want the opposite, the database should generate the id on insert.

Comment: @gotqn No changes after I removed `builder.Property(it => it.Id).ValueGeneratedNever()`

Comment: Well, for fluentAPI, add this `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` and for data annotation you can set `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` I believe it will generate identity value from database autometically.

Comment: Nope, I tried that already. Still having the same error.

Comment: Did you created `[Categories]`  table manually right? If so, could you please drop and recreate it and then try inserting new data.

Comment: `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` is definitely required here. It tells EF what the db model looks like  and EF won't try to insert Id values. If that didn't help it must be something in this hidden `_repository.Insert` method.

Comment: And in this scenario you should start by reverse engineering the Entity model from the database.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 1):

It's because by default `Id` of the entity is `0` and EntityFramework is trying to add value where it is not allowed.

Try this:

```
 builder.HasKey(it => it.Id);
 // NOTE: Never get involved in primary key generation and consider 
 //       they are unique in the domain
 // Remove .ValueGeneratedNever() and use .UseIdentityColumn() instead
 builder.Property(it => it.Id).UseIdentityColumn();
```

Comment: I think the problem is, this is coming in from EF via .Include(). So I'm loading it, and I expect if there are no changes to that entity\row...why would I still get this error?